# Tests that use Fakes/Shims fail on server, but succeed in local

Tags: testing, server, microsoft-fakes

Tests that use Fakes/Shims fail on build server, but succeed in local.

This following error is gone when I remove the test that uses shims. Do I need to do any specific configuration on build server?

On a side note, I'm using shims in my specflow test cases.

```
Run has the following issue(s):
One of the background threads threw exception: 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at lambda_method(Closure , IContextManager )
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments, ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.FireEvents(HookType bindingEvent)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.OnTestRunEnd()
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunner.OnTestRunEnd()
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunnerManager.OnTestRunnerEnd()
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunnerManager.
```

Further debugging gives the following error,
Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.UnitT‌​estIsolationExceptio‌​n: Failed to resolve profiler path from COR_PROFILER_PATH and COR_PROFILER environment variables.

Comment: Finally I'm able to resolve the issue by using the vstest.console.exe instead of mstest.exe. 

The following article mentioned that mstest doesnt support fakes. Only vstest supports it. 

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253138(v=vs.110)
Thanks!

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object error is due to improper disposal of shimsContext. I need to have a null check before I dispose i.e, if(shimsContext != null) { shimsContext.Dispose(); }, earlier I dont have null check. Once I fixed that issue I got following error which is due to MSTest not supports fakes framework Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.UnitTestIsolationException: Failed to resolve profiler path from COR_PROFILER_PATH and COR_PROFILER environment variables.